# Is most significant bit set?

Tags: c++

Is below code a valid way to check if the MSB is set?

```
std::uint8_t data[] = { 0x78, 0xFE, 0x06, 0x99, 0xE5, 0x06, 0xBE  };

for (const auto& byte : data)
{
    auto stopBit =  (byte >> 7) & 1;
    std::cout << stopBit << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Every code is valid, It does what it is supposed to do.

But what are you trying to do?

Comment: Probably not.  "Stopbit" is a term that's used in serial communications.  It is not part of the data, it is added and removed by the UART and the program never sees it.

Comment: @HansPassant This is for decoding a FIX Fast message that is stop bit encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that'll work for single bytes.

Alternatively, you can do `byte & 0x80` to avoid the shifting.

Comment: `byte & 0x80` is obscure. Use `byte & 0b1000'0000` if you are paranoia about shifts. It clearly indicates which bit you are testing for.